# Is it possible to fold/unfold only one function

Tags: folding

I'm trying to fold my c++ code.

Google told me that I should `set foldmethod=indent`. But this is not what I need.

`set foldmethod=indent` makes all of folds happen automatically when I enter a c++ file. And `zc` and `zo` will fold/unfold all of functions. But what I need is that:

1. Don't fold automatically when I enter a c++ file;
2. I only want to fold the function in which the cursor is.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: possible using a custom foldexpression.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt any doc or link?

Comment: The first thing you need to explain is what's wrong with the defaults? I.e. `foldmethod=syntax` which is set by standard `ftplugin`?

Comment: @Matt I doubt it is set by default. At least in my vim default is manual

Comment: @MaximKim Ah, my bad. `fdm=syntax` is not set by default. That's my private setting.

Comment: If you fold the function the cursor is on, you can’t see it’s body—is that what you want? It’s unclear to me.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble  Put the cursor into a function, and fold it. That's what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are ok with `set foldmethod=indent` and don't need to use other methods (syntax, expr or manual) then add to your vimrc:

```
set foldlevelstart=99
```

With this option all your folds would be open for a file you edit(open).

```
'foldlevelstart' 'fdls' number (default: -1)
            global
            {not available when compiled without the |+folding|
            feature}
    Sets 'foldlevel' when starting to edit another buffer in a window.
    Useful to always start editing with all folds closed (value zero),
    some folds closed (one) or no folds closed (99).
```

For the second thing I am not sure what exactly you need, I would use `zc` and `zo` or `za` to close/open/toggle current fold.

PS, you might also like `set foldmethod=syntax` for c/cpp files:

```
augroup cpp | au!
    au FileType c,cpp setl fdm=syntax
augroup END
```

[image]